# Python Exercice

Tags: python, algorithm

I am a Python newbie and stuck with the following question:

Write a program that repeatedly prompts a user for integer numbers until the user enters 'done'. Once 'done' is entered, print out the largest and smallest of the numbers. If the user enters anything other than a valid number catch it with a try/except and put out an appropriate message and ignore the number. Enter 7, 2, bob, 10, and 4 and match the output below.

My solution:

```
largest = None
smallest = None
store=[]

while True:
    num = input("Enter a number: ")
    try:        
        if num == "done" : break
        else:
           store.append(num)
    except:
        print("U have an invalid entry")

largest=max(store)
smallest=min(store)
print ("Invalid input")
print ("Maximum is",largest)
print ("Minimum is",smallest)
```

None of the print statement are being printed out.

Comment: And what's your question? What do you actually need help with?

Comment: why my code isn't giving me the solution to the question. 
None of the print statement are being printed out.

Answer (score 2):

1. `input` returns a string; if the string is not `"done"`, you should try to convert it to an integer with `int()`.
2. If that fails, it will throw `ValueError`; you should catch only that exception. Using a bare `except:` catches ALL exceptions, which is usually a bad idea.
3. You don't need to keep all the numbers in `store`; you only need to keep the lowest and highest so far.

---

I've made a couple more changes:

1. You got rid of `input` in `num = input("Enter a number: ")`; I put it back.
2. When comparing to `None`, use `is` instead of `==`
3. `n < smallest` would throw a TypeError if `smallest` is `None`; we guard against this by checking for `smallest is None` first. `or` is lazy, so `a or b` -> if `a` is True, `b` never gets evaluated, so we never cause an error.

Result:

```
largest = None
smallest = None

while True:
    num = input("Enter a number: ")
    if num == "done":
        break
    try:
        n = int(num)
        if smallest is None or n < smallest:
            smallest = n
        if largest is None or n > largest:
            largest = n
    except ValueError:
        # num cannot be converted to an int
        print ("Invalid input")

print("Smallest is", smallest)
print("Largest is", largest)
```

which runs like

```
Enter a number: 7
Enter a number: 2
Enter a number: bob
Invalid input
Enter a number: 10
Enter a number: 4
Enter a number: done
Smallest is 2
Largest is 10
```

Comment: largest = None

smallest = None

while True:

    try:

     num = ("Enter a number: ")

     if num == "done" : break

     n = int(num)

     if largest < n :

         largest = n

     if smallest == None or smallest > n : smallest = n


    except:

        print ("Invalid input")

print ("Maximum is", largest)


doesn't work

Comment: @raph: post the code as an addition to your posting.  Comments don't have code formatting.  Also note that "doesn't work" is not a problem statement, and that the failure of one implementation attempt does not invalidate Hugh's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your try-except block cannot raise any exception. It's always correct.
You should convert your input to int and this operation can cause an error.

```
# largest = None
# smallest = None
store=[]

while True:
    s = input("Enter a number: ")
    if s == "done":
        break

    try:
        store.append(int(s))
    except:
        print("U have an invalid entry")

largest = max(store)
smallest = min(store)
# print("Invalid input")
print("Maximum is ", largest)
print("Minimum is ", smallest)
```

Comment: If a user is very annoying and does not input at least one number this will raise a ValueError. Since you cannot get max or min from an empty list. Just try running the code and only input done.